# Site with wrong call on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, call

I downloaded the server site and set to run on localhost. But he is not making the call of the files correctly. First, he calls "http://localhost" and then the folder path, with backslash.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

There is a rule set to call all the files:

```
<?php
define("MY_BASE_DIR", 'C:');
define("SITE_PATH", __DIR__ . '/');
define("SITE_VIRTUAL_DIR", str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "", SITE_PATH));
define("ENGINE_PATH", SITE_PATH.'includes/fw/'); // caminho pro FW
define("CMS_ENGINE_PATH", SITE_PATH.'includes/cms/cms.php');
?>
```

I tried to change this rule, but without success /:

This backslash setting is a passage in the code files that have changed or whether it is my local server configuration (I'm using WampServer)?

This is the file that gives way to the files:

```
public function Setup()
{
    parent::Setup();

    if (\Browser::Obsolet())
    {
        $this->context->UpdateYourBrowser();
    }

    if(!defined("ADMIN_DIR")){
        define("ADMIN_DIR", dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) . "/");
        define("ADMIN_URL", DOMAIN . ADMIN_DIR );
    }

    if(!defined("ADMIN_PATH"))
    {
        throw new \Exception("Para acessar um módulo do backend você precisa esta no diretorio do admin/");
    }

    // configura a sessao do usuario
    $this->context->set("USER.SESSION", $this->context->get("USER.SESSION") . ADMIN_PATH . "_ADMIN");

    // configura o template do ADMIN
    // checa se o usuario especificou algum caminho para o template do ADMIN
    $templatePath = $this->context->get("CMS.ADMIN.TEMPLATE_PATH");
    if(!$templatePath){
        $templatePath = ADMIN_PATH;
    }
    $this->context->setTemplatePath($templatePath); //diretorio raiz de templates?
    $this->context->setTemplate($this->context->get('CMS.ADMIN.TEMPLATE')); // seta o template configurado no config.php

    // checa se o usuario especificou algum caminho para o template do ADMIN
    $templateUrl = $this->context->get("CMS.ADMIN.TEMPLATE_URL");
    if(!$templateUrl){
        $templateUrl = ADMIN_DIR; // URI do admin: http://localhost/admin/
    }
    if(!defined("TEMPLATE_URL"))
        define("TEMPLATE_URL", $templateUrl . $this->context->TemplateDir() . $this->context->getTemplate() . "/");
}
```

The files are being called by `TEMPLATE_URL`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_URL ?>static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm still trying to get him to call direct, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SITE_PATH in your rule set from:

```
 define("SITE_PATH", __DIR__ . '/');
```

to:

```
define("SITE_PATH", "/" .str_replace(str_replace("/","\\",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']),"",realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/");
```

Comment: Nothing /:. I also tried modify the "__DIR__" for "__FILE__" also. Without success